# React & TypeScript: Best way to type props dynamically?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

If 'onChange' prop is depending on its 'type' prop, what is the best waty to type Components' props type?

For example,

```
//DynamicField.tsx
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";

type DateProps = {
  type: "date";
  value: string;
  onChange: DateHandler;
};
type DateHandler = (
  date: Date,
  event: React.SyntheticEvent<any, Event> | undefined
) => void;

type TextProps = {
  type: "text";
  value: string;
  onChange: TextHandler;
};
type TextHandler = React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>;

type Props = TextProps | DateProps;

const DynamicField = (props: Props) => {
  if (props.type === "text") {
    return (
      <>
        <input value={props.value} onChange={props.onChange}></input>;
      </>
    );
  } else if (props.type === "date") {
    return (
      <>
        <DatePicker
          onChange={props.onChange}
          selected={new Date(props.value)}
        />
      </>
    );
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};

//App.tsx

const data: Field[] = [
  { type: "text", initialValue: "" },
  { type: "date", initialValue: "2020-10-20" },
  { type: "text", initialValue: "" },
];

function App() {
  const handleField = (type: "date" | "text") => {
    if (type == "text") {
      return (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        console.log(e);
      };
    } else {
      return (date: Date) => {
        console.log(date);
      };
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.map((item) => {
        <>
          <DynamicField
            onChange={handleField(item.type)}
            type={item.type}
            value={item.initialValue}
          />
          ;
        </>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

(Please ignore about handleField function, custom hook will provide handle function dynamically later on.

I get type-imcompatible errors. I've also tried this approach like this

```
type Props = {
    type: "text" | "date";
    value: string;
    onChange: TextHandler | DateHandler;
}
```

The problem of this approach is that I need to check the type of 'onChange' before passing to corresponding input elements.

EDIT: [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-field-76bpy)

Comment: What about using generics? What is the actual error? Can you recreate in a codesandbox?

Comment: @DennisVash  I've never used generics on React prop types. I will try it. I also updated code sandbox link.

Comment: You almost certainly want a discriminated union.